# Hypeyledger composer ping failed for multi peer fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I have setup a fabric network with 1 org, 1 CA, 2 peers, 1 channel. Fabric network works fine and it deploys containers for org, ca, 3 for peers (with couch DB). But when I tried to use composer and try to ping the network I get error on peer -

> 2018-01-14 12:08:16.421 UTC [eventhub_producer] Chat -> ERRO 12d8
>   error during Chat, stopping handler: rpc error: code = Canceled desc =
>   context canceled 2018-01-14 12:13:35.649 UTC [eventhub_producer]
>   validateEventMessage -> DEBU 12d9 ValidateEventMessage starts for
>   signed event 0xc42174f800 2018-01-14 12:13:35.650 UTC
>   [eventhub_producer] Chat -> ERRO 12da Error handling message: event
>   message must be properly signed by an identity from the same
>   organization as the peer: [failed deserializing event creator: [The
>   supplied identity is not valid, Verify() returned x509: certificate
>   signed by unknown authority]]

Below are the sequence of activity that I did

> composer card create -p connection.json -u PeerAdmin -c
>   /home/ubuntu/multipeer/fabric-scripts/hlfv1/composer/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@org1.example.com-cert.pem
>   -k /home/ubuntu/multipeer/fabric-scripts/hlfv1/composer/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore/xxxxxxxxx_sk
>   -r PeerAdmin -r ChannelAdmin
>
> composer card import -f PeerAdmin@hlfv1.card
>
> composer runtime install -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -n commodity-network
>
> composer identity request -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -u admin -s adminpw -d
>   bala02
>
> composer network start -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -a
>   commodity-network@0.0.1.bna -A bala01 -C bala02/admin-pub.pem
>
> composer card create -p connection.json -u bala02 -n commodity-network
>   -c bala02/admin-pub.pem -k bala02/admin-priv.pem
>
> composer card import -f bala02@commodity-network.card
>
> composer network ping -c bala02@commodity-network

Comment: I could able to fix this issue and proceed further with 1 Org, 1 CA & 2 Peer. I created a PeerAdmin card, imported it. I executed composer run time install and created an identity request for a sample network.

Comment: Have you repeated this test?  Is there perhaps an old card with the same name with an Old invalid certificate - maybe clearing out all old cards before you start would help.  
Also when you configured the Fabric did you have TLS enabled or disabled?  Perhaps disabled would help for initial testing.

Comment: I have repeated the test by deleting all the card and recreating it but I get the same error. How to check whether TLS is enabled or disabled?

Comment: You say you have 2 peers. Do both peers show the same error or just 1 ? have you confirmed both peers are joined to the channel ? Have you tried taking the failing peer offline and changing your connection profile to try a single peer ?

Comment: Also curious to know how you verified that your fabric network and channel has been setup and works fine ? did you try installing some simple chaincode to verify this ?

Comment: I got the same error in both the peers. I changed the configuration with 1 peer and followed the same sequence to deploy the compose and it failed with a different error 
 [eventhub_producer] Chat -> ERRO 12d8 Error handling message: error sending response to signature

I checked the docker logs for peer & order and it all fine with they joining the channel

Comment: Yes, I did. chaincode is getting deployed in all the peers.